# Leverage SVN/Git APIs for writing backend of a collaborative web application

Tags: git, svn, web-applications, version-control

My web app needs to do following:

1. Provide a web interface for business analysts to do CRUD operations on business rules.
2. Each business rule is written in a rules language. It has versions. Multiple persons can do CRUD operations on a rule. So at a very high level this whole app is like code management system but for business analysts.
3. Hence it will have only the basic version control functionality like versioning, maybe merging, showing conflicts on save, branching, release etc. but not the advanced features like cherry-pick commits, git stash, etc. Also, unlike Git each user is not pulling the code onto their local machine. Everything is done in browser. It's like the markdown based wiki feature of Gitlab/Github.
4. Can't expect business analysts to learn Git/SVN.
5. Some other functionality will also be there. Hence can't use hosted Gitlab etc.

Question:
Can Git/SVN/any other-version-control-api be leveraged for this functionality instead of writing our own server side code for doing version control etc. ?

Comment: Initially we don't expect very high traffic for this web-app. Some out of the box version control api that gets us going is more important.

Comment: Any success in the pursuit?